# fonts are blocked in web client cors

Tags: cors

While I was working in local everything worked perfectly, now I uploaded to a hosting and the fonts are being blocked by something I've never heard of (CORS). The fonts (and css, js, etc) are in a subdomain because urls are parsed by the index (so paths are not working in the domain). The css/js are working ok.

This is the output in the web console (firefox):

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at /fonts/Oxygen-Regular.ttf. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing). <unknown>
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Oxygen-Regular" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed source: /fonts/Oxygen-Regular.ttf styles.css:10:12
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at /fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing). <unknown>
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Montserrat-Regular" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed source: /fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf styles.css:6:12
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at /fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing). <unknown>
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed source: /fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 bootstrap.css:267:12
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at /fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing). <unknown>
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:2): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed source: /fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff bootstrap.css:267:12
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at /fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing). <unknown>
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:3): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed source: /fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf bootstrap.css:267:12
```

I searched for this problem but i cannot find this especific problem with fonts and the exact error message.

EDIT:

The fix is to enable the header for the domain / folder serving the files. The config can be either in the virtual host block or in a .htaccess file (in the folder where the files are). I prefer setting it in the vhost block:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIf Origin "https://(www|sub1|sub2|sub3).domain.com$" ACAO=$0
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{ACAO}e" env=ACAO
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET"
</IfModule>
```

In this example, the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` will only send the header for the whitelisted domain and subdomains. I redirect from `domain.com` to `www.domain.com` so this example won't accept a domain without `www`.

Comment: Just google how to set the mentioned header with your web server and you are done

Comment: Sorry, what header? Is the first time I have this problem and I'm lost :(

Comment: Access-control-allow-origin, it is shown in the error message. Have a look at enable-Cors.org or use your favorite search engine

Comment: Thanks! Once I've added the line to the .htaccess file, do I have to restart or something?

Comment: Come on, just try ;-) Normally it should become active immediately

Comment: Yeah, I've already done it! I'm just waiting hehehe

Comment: The Edit you made to the question, Adding Header to .htaccess file helped me a lot

Comment: Refer this https://github.com/fontello/fontello/wiki/How-to-setup-server-to-serve-fonts

Comment: actually Same Origin Policy is the blocker, CORS is supposed to be one mechanism to bypass that

Comment: Do you have extra closing parenthesis in your answer? It should be
`SetEnvIf Origin "https://(www|sub1|sub2|sub3).domain.com$" ACAO=$0`
shouldn't it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your browser is complaining about a missing header: Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Because this header is missing your browser does not know that the desired access is legit. Have a look at http://enable-cors.org and choose the configuration appropriate for your server.

You need to configure the server where the fonts are stored !

Comment: I've tried adding headers (see edited) in .htaccess with no luck. About the conf files, I don't know how to access them from the kloxo panel, I've been searching but nothing. Also tried `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` at the beginning of the index.php file.

Comment: Show us a trace of the communication, it can be reached by pressing F12 and going to network. There you should see the headers if your config is correct.

Comment: Ok, I was enabling the header in the domain root folder, not in the subdomain root folder... Thanks!

Comment: @ChazyChaz your suggestion would terminate the CORS poliy entirely(which is not receommended)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had a Laravel application that had an environmental parameter "ASSET_URL" which was pointing to a subdomain, inside .env, I commented that out (by adding # sign at the beginning of the line) and CORS went away!

```
#ASSET_URL=https://dev.mysite.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do two thing either allow CORS or point to same hosting location as that of domain.

Answer (score -1):

I found a easy solution that works for me in Apache cPanel.

Just put the code in the `.htaccess` file.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This allows to load from every domain on the internet and is a serious security issue! You should always specify the origins.

Answer (score -3):

[Interesting gotcha](http://www.gubatron.com/blog/2011/11/29/lighttpd-allow-access-control-allow-origin-headers-on-the-server-status-page/):

> lighttpd allows you to add a custom header for all requests by adding
>   this in a given context:
>
> ```perl
> setenv.add-response-header = ( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" => "*" )
> ```
>
> For this to work, you
>   must enable the `mod_setenv`.  But if you don’t enable this module, before
>   you enable your `mod_status` module, you will never see the custom
>   headers come out of your lighttpd HTTP response header output

Comment: This allows to load from every domain on the internet and is a serious security issue! You should always specify the origins.

Comment: Unless they had a separate process just for that. Anyway,  mentioned as a gotcha (I see link there broken), should have been a comment most probably

Answer (score -5):

Read Tons of Articles About **Why GLYPHICON Was Not Showing Up...**

"How to fix Access-Control-Allow-Origin (CORS origin) Issue for your HTTPS"

And They ALL Had Super Complicated Ways To Try And Fix... What In My Case... Was A SUPER SIMPLE Solution.

**My HTML Code When Glyphicon Not Showing...**

```
<link href="https://www.Example.com/css/ss.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://www.Example.com/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

---

**SOLUTION :**

I Simply REMOVED The www. From The URL For My CSS & Bootstrap Files...

```
<link href="https://Example.com/css/ss.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://Example.com/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

---

And Instantly The GLYPHICON Appeared On My Page!

Hope It's That Simple For You TOO!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thanks for taking the time to answer a question. All of the extra capitalization and exclamation points make your answer feel really intense.

Comment: This answer was so simple and correct, I was compelled to log in to Stack Overflow for the first time in probably a decade, just to upvote it!

Comment: This solution did not help me. Thanks