# Requested font files from Azure CDN being blocked by CORS policy

Tags: css, asp.net, azure, fonts, cdn

So I have an Azure Web Service and an Azure CDN. My web service is running on ASP.Net Core

I make a request for my Website's index.html, which starts downloading assets from the CDN. All the assets get loaded, except for the font files.

Here's the error:

> Access to Font at '*https://**CDN**.azureedge.net/68.0.3/styles/ui-grid.woff*' from origin '*https://**WebApp**.azurewebsites.net*' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '*https://**WebApp**.azurewebsites.net*' is therefore not allowed access.

Here's what one of the requests looks like:
[image]

So what I understand is:

1. Download index.html from Web Server
2. index.html -> download .css from CDN
3. .css -> download font from CDN
4. Blocked?? It seems like the browser is blocking the request, not the CDN, is that correct? If so why? Just because it's a font file request?

Comment: Did you read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33197751/fonts-are-blocked-in-web-client-cors or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25577981/font-from-origin-has-been-blocked-from-loading-by-cross-origin-resource-sharing ?

Comment: It looks like those are for Amazon Simple Storage Service, I don't think I have access to .htaccess, or is that a web server file not a cdn server file?

Answer (score 18):

If using Azure Blob Storage as Origin for your CDN endpoint, the problem could be the CORS configuration in the **Storage Account**.

I initially had all my domains in a separate row under `Allowed Origins` and received the same errors as the OP.
Turns out you can/must place all domains (that should have the same CORS configuration) on the same row, separated by `,` like this:

[image: Storage Account CORS configuration]

Comment: Is there a limit to how long that string can be?

Comment: To get it to work we also had to create a rule in the Standard rules engine to check the Origin header on the request.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-cors

Comment: What do you mean by checking the Origin header @farreachchad? Can you show the rule you had to implement in order for it to work?

Answer (score 5):

In my case, IIS blocks .woff since mimeType is not set, hence you can set that in web.config (and optionally CORS if required) as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
   <staticContent>
        <remove fileExtension=".woff" /> <!-- In case IIS already has this mime type -->
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
        <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
        <!-- In case IIS already has this mime type -->
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/x-font-woff2" />    
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't pull fonts from CDN without proper config - it's a different domain, so browser can't trust this files without proper headers.

You have only one option - set properly header in CDN. If you have access to Apache or NGINX you can set:

Apache

```
<FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff)">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```

NGINX

```
if ($filename ~* ^.*?\.(eot)|(ttf)|(woff)$){
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
```

If you don't have access to server settings you can't use fonts from CDN.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Verizon Premium SKU of Azure CDN, you can also set the CORS headers via the CDN instead of the origin server.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-cors

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this CORS error when trying to serve font files from a blob storage account behind a CDN, even when running locally.

The reference for the font files was a relative reference from a CSS file which was served from the same Blob Storage account.

My fix was to make the reference for the font files an absolute reference to the (same) url in the blob storage account. This meant that the Blob Storage account could apply the CORS policy (that was set in Azure on the Blob storage account) correctly.